# Set default windows app for common middle extension but different last extension

Tags: windows, explorer, file-extension

I want to set the default app for a common middle extension but different last extension files.
My files are usually generated in the format of
`abcd.**YYY**.52asda52asd9a526385das6`
`efeg.**YYY**.6ad5sa6f8ad8asd6a5fa6fa8da6d5a6`

and so on...

How can I do this in W10?